# Rotating Display Causes X11 to Restart Ubuntu Studio 22.04

Tags: drivers, multiple-monitors, amd-graphics, ubuntu-studio, display-rotation

Just upgraded to Ubuntu Studio 22.04 with a fresh install. I have an AMD Radeon HD 7750 with two Dell U2720Q 4k monitors both running 3840x2160. lshw -c video shows the driver=radeon.

I need to rotate one of my monitors 90 degrees to be in portrait mode. In system settings, display configuration, when I click the rotate 90 degrees clockwise icon and then click apply, X11 restarts and I'm back at a login screen and after logging in, the monitor is still in landscape mode.

I've searched all over Google and I see somethings to try for 20.04, but not 22.04. Most things point to a driver issue. I tried installing the latest driver from AMD for the card (15.302) and I get the following:

error: Detected X Server version 'XServer 1.21.1.3_64a' is not supported. Supported versions are X.Org 6.9 or later, up to XServer 1.10 (default:v2:x86_64:lib32:XServer 1.21.1.3_64a:none:5.15.0-33-lowlatency:)
Installation will not proceed.

Not sure what else to try at this point. Any help is appreciated.